# How to extract multiple integers from a String in Java?

Tags: java, string, int, type-conversion

I got a series of string like `"(123, 234; 345, 456) (567, 788; 899, 900)"`.
How to a extract those numbers into an array like `aArray[0]=123, aArray=[234], ....aArray[8]=900;`

Thank you

Comment: I don't think it's nice to downvote the question like this. The one who asked probably is new to programming and assumes there is a magic way to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably overly convoluted, but hay...

The first thing we need to do is remove all the crap we don't need...

```
String[] crap = {"(", ")", ",", ";"};
String text = "(123, 234; 345, 456) (567, 788; 899, 900)";
for (String replace : crap) {
    text = text.replace(replace, " ").trim();
}
// This replaces any multiple spaces with a single space
while (text.contains("  ")) {
    text = text.replace("  ", " ");
}
```

Next, we need to seperate the individual elements of the string into a more manageable form

```
String[] values = text.split(" ");
```

Next, we need to convert each `String` value to an `int`

```
int[] iValues = new int[values.length];
for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {

    String sValue = values[index];
    iValues[index] = Integer.parseInt(values[index].trim());

}
```

Then we display the values...

```
for (int value : iValues) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Strategy:** Find one or more numbers that are together, through a regular expression to be added to a list.

**Code:**

```
    LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("(123, 234; 345, 456) (567, 788; 899, 900)");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        list.add(matcher.group());
    }
    String[] array = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

**Output:**

```
[123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 788, 899, 900]
```

Comment: This is what I would do. Just one thing though. Looking at the format of the string, Mr Quoi might want a different structure. It looks like a list of lists with pairs in them. `List<List<Tupel<Integer, Integer>>>` maybee? Still, I would go for the regex solution.

Comment: Check the element 8 of the desire array in the question. Thats give me the clue, of how the array must be. ;)

Comment: Just code answers are usually not welcome in Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 5):

You've almost certainly seen the quote:

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use
>   regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

But regular expressions really are your friend for this sort of thing.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

class Numbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "(123, 234; 345, 456) (567, 788; 899, 900)";
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(s);
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while(m.find()) {
            numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group()));
        }
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
[123, 234, 345, 456, 567, 788, 899, 900]
```

Comment: Did someone really downvote my solution on this? Why not leave a comment to explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through each character and store numbers in a temporary array until you find a character(like `,`, `;`) then store the data from temporary array into your array and then empty that temporary array for next use.

Answer (score 0):

Since your numbers are separated by a specific set of characters, you can take a look at the [`.split(String regex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

As there may be a number of different delimeters in your string, you can go through it and replace all non-digit characters with `spaces`. Then you can use `split("\\s")` to split your string into an array of substrings with numbers. And finally convert them to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

This method will extract integers from a given string. It also processes strings where other characters are used to separate numbers, not just the ones in your example:

```
public static Integer[] extractIntegers( final String source ) {
    final int    length = source.length();
    final char[] chars  = source.toCharArray();

    final List< Integer > list = new ArrayList< Integer >();

    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {

        // Find the start of an integer: it must be a digit or a sign character
        if ( chars[ i ] == '-' || chars[ i ] == '+' || Character.isDigit( chars[ i ] ) ) {
            final int start = i;

            // Find the end of the integer:
            for ( i++; i < length && Character.isDigit( chars[ i ] ); i++ )
                ;

            // Now extract this integer:
            list.add( Integer.valueOf( source.substring( start, i ) ) );
        }
    }

    return list.toArray( new Integer[ list.size() ] );
}
```

**Note:** Since the internal `for` loop positions after an integer and the outside `for` loop will increase the `i` variable when searching for the next integer, the algorithm will require at least one character to separate the integers but I think this is desirable. For example the `"-23-12"` source will produce the numbers `[ -23, 12 ]` and NOT `[ -23, -12 ]` (but `"-23 -12"` will produce [ -23, -12 ] as expected).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to use of combination of `String.indexOf()` (or something like this) and `NumberFormat.parse(ParsePosition)` methods. An algorithm would be following:

1. start from the beginning of string
2. find a number starting from that position
3. parse using mentioned method of NumberFormat which will stop on non-digit
   character and return a value
4. repeat 2) starting from that position (until end of string is reached)

At the same time, the string has a particular structure, so IMHO some parser would be better approach as it would also check a correctness of format (if it's necessary, I don't know). There are a lot of tools for generating Java code from a description of a grammar (like ANTLR, etc.). But it might be too complex solution for the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use regular expression to get your result. Something like this maybe:

```
String string = "(123, 234; 345, 456) (567, 788; 899, 900)";
String[] split = string.split("[^\\d]+");
int number; 
ArrayList<Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(int index = 0; index < split.length; index++){
    try{
        number = Integer.parseInt(split[index]);
        numberList.add(number);
    }catch(Exception exe){

    }
}

Integer[] numberArray = numberList.toArray(new Integer[numberList.size()]);
for(int index = 0; index < numberArray.length; index++){
    System.out.println(numberArray[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way. Might be good if u want to write less code, might be bad if u cannot add libs to your project

```
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.collect.Iterables;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String text = "(123, 234; 345, 456) (567, 788; 899, 900)";
        Splitter splitter = Splitter.onPattern("[,;\\)\\(]").omitEmptyStrings();
        String[] cleanString = Iterables.toArray(splitter.split(text), String.class);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cleanString));

    }
```

AM sure the gurus can clean it further.

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (int i = 0; i < faces.total(); i++) 
 {
    CvRect r = new CvRect(cvGetSeqElem("(123, 234; 345, 456)", i));             
    String x=""+Integer.toString(r.x());
    String y=""+Integer.toString(r.y());
    String w=""+Integer.toString(r.width());
    String h=""+Integer.toString(r.height());
    for(int j=0;j<(4-Integer.toString(r.x()).length());j++)   x="0"+x;
    for(int j=0;j<(4-Integer.toString(r.y()).length());j++)   y="0"+y;
    for(int j=0;j<(4-Integer.toString(r.width()).length());j++)   w="0"+w;
    for(int j=0;j<(4-Integer.toString(r.height()).length());j++)   h="0"+h;
    r_return=""+x+y+w+h;
 }
```

Above code will return a string "0123023403540456"

```
int[] rectArray = new int[rectInfo.length()/4];
for(int i=0;i<rectInfo.length()/4; i++)
{
    rectArray[i]=Integer.valueOf(rectInfo.substring(i*4, i*4+4));
}
```

and it will get [123, 234, 345, 456]