# Efficiently extracting numbers from a java string (already tried guava and regular expressions)

Tags: java, regex, string, guava, tokenize

Trying to efficiently extract some numbers from a string and have tried

- java.util.regex.Matcher
- com.google.common.base.Splitter

The results were :

- via Regular Expression: 24417 ms
- via Google Splitter: 17730 ms

Is there another faster way you can recommend ?

I know similar questions asked before e.g. [How to extract multiple integers from a String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721261/how-to-extract-multiple-integers-from-a-string-in-java) but my emphasis is on making this fast (but maintainable/simple) as it happens a lot.

---

**EDIT : Here are my final results which tie in with those from Andrea Ligios below:**

- Regular Expression (without brackets) : 18857
- Google Splitter (without the superflous trimResults() method): 15329
- Martijn Courteaux answer below: 4073

---

```
import org.junit.Test;

import com.google.common.base.CharMatcher;
import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Sample {

    final static int COUNT = 50000000;
    public static final String INPUT = "FOO-1-9-BAR1"; // I want 1, 9, 1

    @Test
    public void extractNumbers() {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            // Output is list of 1, 9, 1
            Demo.extractNumbersViaGoogleSplitter(INPUT);
        }
        System.out.println("Total execution time (ms) via Google Splitter: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));


        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            // Output is list of 1, 9, 1
            Demo.extractNumbersViaRegEx(INPUT);
        }
        System.out.println("Total execution time (ms) Regular Expression: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

    }
}

class Demo {

    static List<Integer> extractNumbersViaGoogleSplitter(final String text) {

        Iterator<String> iter = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.JAVA_DIGIT.negate()).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(text).iterator();
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            result.add(Integer.parseInt(iter.next()));

        }
        return result;
    }
    /**
     * Matches all the numbers in a string, as individual groups. e.g.
     * FOO-1-BAR1-1-12 matches 1,1,1,12.
     */
    private static final Pattern NUMBERS = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)");

    static List<Integer> extractNumbersViaRegEx(final String source) {
        final Matcher matcher = NUMBERS.matcher(source);
        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        if (matcher.find()) {
            do {
                result.add(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(0)));
            } while (matcher.find());
            return result;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does your measurement for the regex approach change if you remove the parentheses from the pattern?

Comment: as m.buettner pointed out group here is unnecessary and still you are referring to wrong group..

Comment: Your benchmarking test is flawed. You are doing one test after the other. The second test will have the benefit of the JVM being warmed up already. Run each test in its own JVM invocation.

Comment: Use google caliper for benchmarking

Comment: m.buettner, I have tested now with Pattern.compile("\\d+") and it has gone from 24s to 18s. According to JProfiler, NUMBERS.matcher is indeed a hotspot

Comment: @k1eran see what a difference capturing makes ;). never use parentheses unless you have to. and if you have to, use `(?: ... )` instead of plain parentheses, unless you *actually* need to backreference or capture something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a very quick algorithm:

```
public List<Integer> extractIntegers(String input)
{
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int index = 0;
    int v = 0;
    int l = 0;
    while (index < input.length())
    {
        char c = input.charAt(index);
        if (Character.isDigit(c))
        {
            v *= 10;
            v += c - '0';
            l++;
        } else if (l > 0)
        {
            result.add(v);
            l = 0;
            v = 0;
        }
        index++;
    }
    if (l > 0)
    {
        result.add(v);
    }
    return result;
}
```

This code took on my machine 3672 milliseconds, for "FOO-1-9-BAR1" and 50000000 runs. I'm on a  2.3 GHz core.

Comment: What's up with the clever char hack ;-)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: for the sake of the knowledge, i've run the different solutions on the same (old) machine, with 5000000 iterations (one zero removed from OP question), here are the results:

> Total execution time (ms) via Martijn Courteaux algorithm: 2562
>
> Total execution time (ms) via Char comparison: 6891
>
> Total execution time (ms) Regular Expression (WITH parenthesis): 12937
>
> Total execution time (ms) Regular Expression (WITHOUT parenthesis): 12297

---

This is circa two time faster than regex:

```
   startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
   for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
       // Output is list of 1, 9, 1
       Demo.extractNumbersViaCharComparison(INPUT);
   }
   System.out.println("Total execution time (ms) via Char comparison: " + 
                              (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
```

[...]

```
    static List<Integer> extractNumbersViaCharComparison(final String text) {

        final List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        char[] chars = text.toCharArray();

        StringBuilder sB = new StringBuilder();
        boolean previousWasDigit = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(chars[i])){
                previousWasDigit = true;
                sB.append(chars[i]);
            } else {
                if (previousWasDigit){
                    result.add(Integer.valueOf(sB.toString()));                 
                    previousWasDigit = false;
                    sB = new StringBuilder();
                }                   
            }
        }
        if (previousWasDigit)
            result.add(Integer.valueOf(sB.toString()));

        return result;
    }
```

By the way the other solution is a lot more elegant, +1

Comment: -1: Your algorithm doesn't work for input where it has to extract numbers > 9, eg: `FOO-23-BAR98` should result in 23 and 98, but your code will return 2, 3, 9, 8.

Comment: you're right, i've edited for completeness but your solution is definitely the sweetest (and fastest) one

Comment: -1 removed :) Allocating StringBuilders in a loop looks *very* inefficient.

Comment: Only when a (n-long) number ends... what would you suggest instead?

Comment: Oh my... :D 
I thought your comment was related to my approach, StringBuilder is faster than using Strings or a StringBuffer;
I already said that your (upvoted) answer is by far the better in this case, should I edit mine to use your logic ? :) that would be plagiarism ! :)